# Rails app to check the status of a server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http, weblogic, net-http

I want to achieve a problem, where we manually go and check a webapp/server if it is up/down. I want to build a rails app which can automate this task.

Consider my app url is: **HostName:PORT/Route?Params** (may or may not have port in url)

I checked 'net/http'

```
def check_status()
      @url='host'
      uri = URI(@url)
      http = Net::HTTP.new(@url,port)
      response = http.request_get('/<route>?<params>')
      if response == Net::HTTPSuccess
        @result='Running'
      else
        @result='Not Running'
      end
    end
```

I am facing error at ,

```
response = http.request_get('/<route>?<params>')
```

when the app is down throwing 'Failed to open TCP connection to URL' which is correct.

Can you guys help me find some new solution or how can I improve the above implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it's working as intended and you just need to handle the error that's returned when the app is down, wrap it in a rescue block.

```
    def check_status()
      @url='host'
      uri = URI(@url)
      http = Net::HTTP.new(@url,port)
      begin
        response = http.request_get('/<route>?<params>')
        rescue TheClassNameOfThisErrorWhenSiteIsDown
          @result = 'Not Running'
        end
        if response == Net::HTTPSuccess
          @result='Running'
        else
          @result='Not Running'
        end
      end
    end
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the info. I made use of rescue block and made few tweaks. Its working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Just came across this old question. Net::HTTP methods `get` and `head` don't raise an exception. So use one of these instead.

```
def up?(site)
  Net::HTTP.new(site).head('/').kind_of? Net::HTTPOK
end

up? 'www.google.com' #=> true
```